# Bind Not Starting on Ubuntu 14.04 with Plesk 12.5

Tags: 14.04, server, webserver

I've recently installed Plesk 12.5 and i'm having some issues with bind.

Whenever i start the service i get this error message in my syslog

```
Mar 11 18:33:05 ded named[9007]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Mar 11 18:33:05 ded named[9007]: open: /etc/named.conf: permission denied
Mar 11 18:33:05 ded named[9007]: loading configuration: permission denied
Mar 11 18:33:05 ded named[9007]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

I have tried this:

https://kb.plesk.com/en/123075

With no luck.

I do not have AppArmor installed currently cause i saw a lot of people were having issues with plesk and apparmor so i went ahead and deleted that first.

My System:

Plesk 12.5 
Ubuntu 14.04

Is there any solution to this problem? I have searched everywhere for a solution but i can not seem to find one.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem.
What are the permissions of /etc/named.conf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top chroot-directory /var/named/run-root didn't have proper chmod, it was 744 instead of 755 so the user bind wasn't able to access subfolders.

Already solved on another board, he probably forgot to mark this as solved here.